# How to modify a Series(DataFrame) of Pandas in place during iterating?

Tags: python, pandas, reference, iteration, in-place

I need to revice values in a Series(column) of Pandas according to another function.

During iterating, after I get the result, I don't want to lookup the series twice, becasue I guess that it wastes time and is not required.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C'])
for index, value in s.items():
    s[index] = func_hard_to_vectorized(value)    # lookup again!!!
```

In words of C++, **"How to get a reference to that cell?"**

What I want looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C'])
for index, value in s.items():
    value = func_hard_to_vectorized(value)    # change in place
    assert_equal(s[index], value)
```

A same problem about DataFrame exists also, perhaps more heavily influence the performance.

**How to get a reference to a row of Pandas.DataFrame?**

Comment: If you are looking over items to apply a custom function, the time to set the value is likely negligible compared to the computation. Anyway, you cannot have a reference to an item of the Series other than what you already do. Are you sure the function cannot be vectorized ?

Comment: Thanks! I simplized the problem. In fact the type of looking-up key is not a integer, but a np.Datetime64, and my dataframe is huge(a few millions rows), so seeking is expensive.

Comment: Have you tried to use `apply` or a list comprehension to avoid inserting at each step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to insert your data only once, not at each step:

```
s[:] = [func_hard_to_vectorized(v) for v in s]
```

Or:

```
s[:] = s.apply(func_hard_to_vectorized)
```

Thus insertion will only occur **once** with all items at once.

If you don't care having a new Series (i.e. if there is not another name pointing to the Series):

```
s = s.apply(func_hard_to_vectorized)
```

can also be used.

##### example using both index/value:

```
s = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C'])

def f(idx, v):
    return f'{v}_{idx}'

s[:] = [f(idx, v) for idx, v in s.items()]
```

Modified `s`:

```
0    A_0
1    B_1
2    C_2
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact func_hard_to_vectorized not only need the value of the cell, but also the index. How should I get them work? Maybe I should use a lambda?

Comment: I added an example